# Functions of random variables problem

Tags: probability

Random variable $X$ has uniform distribution on ($0,1$). The question is to find the distribution of $U=|X-1/3|$.
So, by using the definition of continuous variables, I got to the equation $Fx(u+1/3)-Fx(-u+1/3)$, and that is correct.
Now, I don't understand how to subtract these two functions, since one is non-zero on the interval $(-1/3,2/3)$ and the other on the interval $(-2/3,1/3)$.
The answer in the book is $2u$ on ($0,1/3$), $u+1/3$ on ($1/3,2/3$), and $1$ after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is immediate that $U$ takes values in $[0,\frac23)$ almost surely.

This leads to $F_U(u)=0$ if $u<0$ and $F_U(u)=1$ if $u\geq\frac23$.

After this preparation it is time to look at $u\in[0,\frac23)$.

If $u\in[0,\frac13)$ then: $$F_U(u)=F_X(u+\frac13)-F_X(-u+\frac13)=(u+\frac13)-(-u+\frac13)=2u$$

If $u\in[\frac13,\frac23)$ then: $$F_U(u)=F_X(u+\frac13)-F_X(-u+\frac13)=(u+\frac13)-0=u+\frac13$$

Comment: Can you explain why does it surely take values from 0 to 2/3?

Comment: If $u=|x-\frac13|$ and $0<x<1$ then $0\leq u<\frac23$. Here $u$ and $x$ are random variables with $0<x<1$ almost surely.

Comment: Thanks, solved, I didn't remember to determine the values of u.

Comment: You are welcome, and can also take a look at the question that you accidently duplicated.